# AngularJS Directive to Controller communication with "Controller as ...." syntax

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm using the "Controller as" syntax and am in a situation where I'd like the Directive to communicate with the Controller.

I can get this to work when I do NOT use the "Controller as" syntax.   Plunkr links below for both working and non-working versions.

Also - I'm curious to hear if the approach is in line with the "angular way".

Does NOT work:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <div char-count>I like characters, they fill content with stuffs.</div>
  <p>{{main.chars}} characters inside the char-count directive!</p>
</body>
```

and...

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 
  function($scope) {
    this.name = 'World';
    this.chars = 0;
    this.setCharCount = function(elem) {
      this.chars = elem[0].innerHTML.length - 1;
    }
  }
]);

app.directive('charCount', ['$window',
  function($window) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.name = "this setting of scope works!";
        scope.setCharCount(elem);
        elem.css("width", scope.chars + "px");
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Plunkr Working Version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9JaQDwxDmE9uDqq7v0Xv?p=preview

Plunkr Non-workign version with "Controller as" syntax:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dIoq9r66mOhuMSQK7woj?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "controller as" version, you are assigning the methods and properties to `this` (the controller), which is made available on the scope under the "as" name you gave it (in this case, you're using "MainCtrl as main" so it the controller would be accessible as `scope.main`). The working version of your "controller as" directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('charCount', ['$window',
  function($window) {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.main.name = "this setting of scope works!";
        scope.main.setCharCount(elem);
        elem.css("width", scope.main.chars + "px");
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Problematic.  Worked and makes sense; feel a bit silly.  New to Angular and bouncing around what makes sense to go in Directive and what in Controller (without a service) according to Angular's recommended methodology.